# Odds of testing the good light bulb

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, conditional-probability

> We have three light bulbs on a shelf. We randomly pick one for
> testing. We know that among the bulbs there are two relatively
> non-optimal ('bad') and one relatively optimal ('good') regarding
> luminosity.
>
> Let $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ denote the three bulbs, where
> $\alpha$ is the appropriate bulb.
>
> The corresponding probabilities that a given bulb will produce maximal
> luminosity per trial are $P_{\alpha}$, $P_{\beta}$, and $P_{\gamma}$,
> respectively.
>
> We carry out $N$ independent tests for which we observe that the
> chosen bulb worked well $k$ times.
>
> What's the probability that we picked up the the good one for testing?

---

**My solution:**

Let $A$ denote the event that we picked out the appropriate bulb, and let $B$ denote the event that $k$ successes occurred in $N$ trials.

Then the desired conditional probability is the following:
\begin{align*}
P(A \mid B) &= \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}\\ &= 
\frac{\binom{N}{k}\cdot P_{\alpha}^{k} \cdot\left( 1 - P_{\alpha}\right)^{N -k}}{\binom{N}{k}\cdot P_{\alpha}^{k} \cdot\left( 1 - P_{\alpha}\right)^{N -k} + \binom{N}{k}\cdot P_{\beta}^{k} \cdot\left( 1 - P_{\beta}\right)^{N -k} + \binom{N}{k}\cdot P_{\gamma}^{k} \cdot\left( 1 - P_{\gamma}\right)^{N -k}}\\
 &= \frac{P_{\alpha}^{k} \cdot\left( 1 - P_{\alpha}\right)^{N -k}}{P_{\alpha}^{k} \cdot\left( 1 - P_{\alpha}\right)^{N -k} + P_{\beta}^{k} \cdot\left( 1 - P_{\beta}\right)^{N -k} + P_{\gamma}^{k} \cdot\left( 1 - P_{\gamma}\right)^{N -k}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: +1 : to your question, for nice presentation, and good work shown.  Independent of that, your analysis seems spot on to me.

Comment: It is not clear what the probabilities $P_x$ refer to. What happens with probability $(1-P_x)$? And does the quality of bulb correlate with $P_x$?

Comment: Yes, the final result looks correct. If you were writing this as a solution to be graded or to explain to others, you might add in a few more words to explain and/or the step $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$.

Comment: @user Clear to me. "The corresponding probabilities that a given bulb will produce maximal luminosity per trial is $P_\alpha$, $P_\beta$ and $P_\gamma$, respectively."

Comment: @aschepler Is this maximal luminosity known? What is a "success"? What means "one of the lamp is relatively optimal"?

Comment: @user Okay, I do assume in the OP that "appropriate bulb" and "good one" [bulb] mean the same thing, and that "produce maximal luminosity" and "worked well" and "success" [in a "trial"] all mean the same thing. I thought that was obvious. The value of maximal luminosity is irrelevant, since we have names for the probability of a successful trial, the number of successful trials, and the number of total trials.

Comment: I edited the post solely to improve clarity/legibility in the proposed question and solution (the excessive use of exclamation marks and seemingly arbitrary line breaks made it rather difficult to parse).

I don't believe I actually changed anything mathematically, but if I did feel free to edit to correct any such mistake.